# Umbraco No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7, surface-controller

I am trying to render a partial view in Umbraco. I have a `BaseLayout.cshtml`,`Homepage.cshtml`,`BaseLayoutViewModel`,`HomepageViewModel`

This is my BaseLayout View

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<View_Models.BaseLayoutViewModel>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    @Html.Action("GetPrimaryNavbar", "PrimaryNavbar", Model) //This is there the site throws an error.
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

This is my BaseLayout Model. Homepage model inherits from base layout.

```
public class BaseLayoutViewModel : PublishedContentModel
    {
        public BaseLayoutViewModel(IPublishedContent content) : base(content)
        {
        }

        public string PageTitle => this.GetPropertyValue<string>(FieldNames.BaseLayout.PageTitle);
        public string PageDescription => this.GetPropertyValue<string>(FieldNames.BaseLayout.PageDescription);
        public string NavigationName => this.GetPropertyValue<string>(FieldNames.BaseLayout.NavigationName);
    }
```

My PrimaryNavbar Partial view is:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<View_Models.PrimaryNavbarViewModel>
<header>
<ul>
<li>
</li
</ul>
</header>
```

And the controller for the PrimaryNavbar is:

```
 public class PrimaryNavbarController : SurfaceController
    {
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult GetPrimaryNavbar(RenderModel model)
        {
            //var primaryNavbarViewModel = new PrimaryNavbarViewModel(model.Content);

            return PartialView("PrimaryNavbar");//, primaryNavbarViewModel);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Adding Full Error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Source Error:


Line 28: <body>
Line 29: 
Line 30:     @Html.Action("GetPrimaryNavbar", "PrimaryNavbar", Model)
Line 31: 
Line 32:     @RenderBody()


Stack Trace:


[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +138
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +105
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +272

[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Object type 'Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +346
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +744
   Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +460
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +137
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +1167
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +170
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +455
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +170
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +881
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +170
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +699
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +94
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +170
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +539
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Func`1 func) +27
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +3614
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage) +131
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter) +595
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues) +114
   ASP._Page_Views_BaseLayout_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\USERNAME\documents\visual studio 2015\projectsViews\BaseLayout.cshtml:30
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +253
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass3.<RenderPageCore>b__2(TextWriter writer) +311
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +108
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +89
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +310
   Umbraco.Core.Profiling.ProfilingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +232
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +375
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +90
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +833
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +833
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +833
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +186
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +399
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +137
```

I cant understand why I am getting "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." Can someone help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: Added full error message, thanks

Comment: Can you include your `RenderModel` class code?

Comment: Maybe you can add this line to your class and test: `public RenderModel (){}`

Comment: RenderModel is a umbraco class. Its used in route hijacking

Comment: In line 30, are you sure you have your model defined, right?

Comment: Yup. It is definitely defined on line 30, I have been doing some random resting and if in the PrimaryNavbarController I remove the RenderModel attribute in the GetPrimaryNavbar action it doesn't throw an error. :s

Comment: I think i have it..

Comment: Can you post the result of `Model.GetType()` in the view?

Comment: Model type gives: `Umbraco.Core.Models.PublishedContent.PublishedContentType`

Comment: And your method `GetPrimaryNavbar` is expecting a different model type `RenderModel model`

Comment: In Umbraco they can be used even though they are of differnt type as my custom class inherits from base class "PublishedContentModel"

Comment: I have found the answer, the model needs to be sent like this `@Html.Action("GetPrimaryNavbar", "PrimaryNavbar", new { model = Model })`

Thanks for your help pal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the issue you need to send the model like this:

`@Html.Action("GetPrimaryNavbar", "PrimaryNavbar", new { model = Model })`

Comment: Any explanation on why?